# div_for embedded ruby question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When you run `<%= div_for X do%><%end%>` it creates the unique id = X_number. I want to know how you reference a specific div by its unique id with a variable? Is it like #@X.id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

e.g. using jQuery `$('#{ dom_id(x) }')` but I am not sure if I understand your question correctly

Comment: is the `#` for interpolation or to represent the id? what does `dom_id(x)` return?